# How to have Google Form submit event trigger be caught by a Flask website to update that website?

Tags: flask, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a website written on Flask, and I would like to update it when answers to a Google Form has been submitted.

More precisely, I have already associated the form to a Google spreadsheet and I can read that spreadsheet from Flask, but the key component missing is how to trigger the website to update its content when new answers have been submitted to the form.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Webhook solution:

**Google Forms:**

1. Enter the Google Forms editor

   2. Click 3 vertical dots next to profile picture, and select 'script editor'
   3. Customize this snippet to your WebHook url and set a custom token (this is not really secure, but better than nothing ).

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const url = "https://example.com/webhook";

  var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({"token": "sometokenheretocheckonbackend"})
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

( Dialog may popup where you have to approve that you connect to an unauthorized service )

**Handling on the Flask side:**

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from flask import (
    abort,
    request
)


@blueprint.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():

    payload = request.get_json()

    if payload.get('token') != "sometokenheretocheckonbackend":
        abort(HTTPStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)

    # Update your content

    return jsonify({'success': True}), HTTPStatus.OK
```

### Periodic updates (Alternative solution):

I would consider launching a daemon Thread that periodically updates this content. This is obviously not as elegant, but should work quite stable and wouldn't be much more demanding for the server if the content update procedure is reasonably lightweight.

Comment: Thank you very much Kristof for this solution, it seems to be a solution addressing exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Form Submit trigger to trigger a Google Apps Script function that calls out to your Flask site and triggers the update.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thank you Cameron. I am interested in knowing which python module I should use in Flask to do that, with ideally a stub of code on which functions are used Google side and which ones are used Flask side.

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately I can't help on the Flask side, I haven't worked with ti before. You'll need a way to receive an HTTP request from the Apps Script side.